# Big O notation of three for loops

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

What would be the complexity of the following code? would it be N^2*log(n)?

```
for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++)
{
   for (int k = m; k >= 1; k--)
   {
      for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
      {
          //do something here
      }
    }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why do think it would be `n^2log(n)`?

Comment: @ralis - the correct approach is to **analyse** the code rather than guessing.  (And the answer is "no it isn't").

Comment: @ Stephen C- what do you mean?

Comment: @StephenC Unless you are sitting a multi-choice exam right now.

Comment: @ralis - Didn't your teacher teach you how to do complexity analysis from first principles???

Comment: @DavidWallace - Yea well ... multiple choice questions like that are designed to test your intuition, and the student should have developed his / her intuition by doing a number of example analyses before hand.  Guessing is never the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long does the innermost loop take given the running time of the body of the loop is `O(C)`? `O(C*k)`

How long does the second loop take? `O(C*(1+2+3+...+m)) = O(C*m²)`

How long does the whole code snipplet take? `O(C*(1²+2²+3²+...+n²)) = O(C*n³)`

For summing polynomials see [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: How did you get to `O(C*(1²+2²+3²+...+n²))`? The actual number of iterations is `1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + ... (1+2+3+...+n)` -- the sum from 1 to n of (n * (n+1))/2. Were you suggesting the former is an exact count, or just using it as a loose upper bound of the actual count?

Comment: @AndyThomas: The exact count is irrelevant here because of the O-notation. I'm not saying it's an exact count, but that everything with a power below 2 can be safely ignored. (Faulhaber's formula tells you that any sum of a polynomial of degree `x` results in a polynomial of degree `x+1`)

Answer (score 1):

The first loop is executed n times.
The second loop executes n/2 times.
The third loop is executed k/2 times, which equals to n/4 times.

This gives you a O(n^3) complexity.

Empirical test:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n = 1000;

    long first = 0, second = 0, third = 0;

    for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++)
    {
        first++;
       for (int k = m; k >= 1; k--)
       {

          second++;
          for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
          {
              third++;
          }
        }
     }

    cout << first << " " << second << " " << third << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
1000 500500 167167000
```

Comment: I think you have miscounted the number of iterations of the second and third loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sigma notation, you can come up with the following:

[image]